# Trouble with reading file

Tags: android

In my app I have to set one password from a settings page and write it to a file, After that when i enter into the home page i have to read that file if the file is null i have to enter to the settinngs page,

The code used for it is.....

```
   try {
              System.out.println("Enter try block!!!");
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME1);
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                data = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("data from settings file"+data);
                System.out.println("-------1Data Read From File is:1" + data);
               if(data.equals(null))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have to set a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in1 = new Intent();
                    in1.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SetteingsPage.class);
                    startActivity(in1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { 

            }
```

If the password is already set,Then the code is working properly..But if it is null it is not entering into settings class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your if-condition something like,

```
if(data == null || data.equals("") || data.equals("null"))
```

Also, if File is not available, then `openFileInput()` throws `FileNotFoundException`

you have to add catch clause something like,

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have to set a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Intent in1 = new Intent();
  in1.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SetteingsPage.class);
  startActivity(in1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here. First, if the file doesn't exist, you don't get past `openFileInput` because it throws an exception. Second, you may be getting an empty line, which isn't null. You should try doing something like:

```
if(data==null || data.equals("")) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure you will get a `FileNotFoundException` if the file is not present when you try to read it.

Try this code to see if the file is present.

`File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME1);`

`if(file.exists()) { ... }`